# Windows shows different time when I switch between powershell and cmd.exe

Tags: powershell, iis, windows-server-2019

2 weeks ago our government decided to remove `Daylight saving time` from our time offset. So we have the same +3:30 as for whole year, from now on.

I have hosted an `Asp.Net` application on `Windows Server 2019 Core`, I know that this setting is configurable with `Adjust for daylight saving time` in non-core versions of `Windows`. but in `Windows server core` I tried to use this command on `cmd.exe`:

```
 tzutils /s "Iran Standard Time_dstoff"
```

`_dstoff` is being used to disable daylight saving time.

Now `time` command shows correct time in `cmd.exe`, but in the Powershell `Get-Date` show +4:30 (Daylight saving is still active).

It seems that my ASP.NET application follows what Powershell time.

I really don't understand it.

Is there any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have talked to our IT team and they used this command:

```
 sconfig
```

on `Windows Server Core` using option `9' (Date and Time) I was able to access Date&Time window. I changed it daylight setting there and my timezone got corrected.